# MySQL using NULL / NOT NULL VARCHAR instead of TINYINT

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm recording form data from a user, and storing that data in a MySQL database. Many of the questions are Yes/No questions. After a little research I decided to go with TINYINT for the datatype. Now, if one of the questions will require a text input if the answer is "Yes" but no text input if the answer is "No" obviously I will need a VARCHAR for that input.

```
CREATE TABLE `UserResponse` (
    `question1` TINYINT NOT NULL,       # 0="No", 1="Yes"
    `question1Details` VARCHAR(45) NULL
)
```

So my question is... Since the VARCHAR will always be NULL when the TINYINT is 0, would it make more sense to just have the VARCHAR and forget about the TINYINT for "Yes"/"No"?

```
CREATE TABLE `UserResponse` (
    `question1` VARCHAR(45) NULL        # NULL="No", !NULL="Yes" + details
)
```

My thoughts: Using two columns could clutter up the database if there are many instances of this type of question (could mean 40 columns instead of 20, for example). As for space... the VARCHAR is required regardless, and its value unaffected whether we use the TINYINT or not. So if we removed the TINYINT it would save 1 byte per instance per row. The only negative thing I see with that is the front-end code that reads/modifies the table will be slightly more complicated and less readable by having to interpret the NULL / NOT NULL to get data for 2 questions from the same column, instead of having a simple 1 column per question relationship.

Either way could be done, and either way would work fine. But what is the best practice? If you came across either method while working on a database designed by someone else, would it matter to you that they used that method as opposed to the other?

Answer (score 0):

This is really quite optional.  I would go for having only one column and testing for `NULL`s.  Otherwise, you have to think about how to keep the two values in sync.

Unfortunately, MySQL supports neither constraints nor computed columns, so maintaining consistency is more difficult than it needs to be.

On the other hand, you should probably have a table with one row per user and per question.  That is much more flexible than adding questions in as columns.  In fact, survey design is something of a science unto itself, but you have to consider that questions are added, removed, and modified over time.